# Handle replace nodes due to remove or crash at Artifactory

Tags: nodes, artifactory, crush

If node is removed or crashed how it is typically handled by Artifactory? How to recover artifacts in this case?
Is it difference between Edge and Artifactory clusters in this case?

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to be much generic. Let me cover few scenarios.

1. Artifactory is running on a single node connecting to a filestore(a separate NFS drive/S3 etc) and connecting to a database that is separately avaiable. In this case, if the Artfactory server crashes, we can restore everything from the filestore and database. (or even with the backups of filestore and database)
2. Artifactory is running on HA (more than 1 node) and there is a reverse proxy that is redirecting the calls. In this case let us believe Artifactory is using a separate filestore and database. Now in this case, even if one node is down Artifactory will still be serving the requests. It's a like a plug and play when you are on HA. We can always restore to orignal state.

The key point here is, as long as we have artifactory configuation details, filestore backup and database backup, we can always restore Artifactory.
If you are looking for Artifactory to heal by itself, then it is not possible. Please elaborate a little in that case.

Comment: I try to understand process node recovering more in depth, by steps Filestore is part of node, right? So recovering node can make sync with other node for sync filestore?